# Trouble with the directory to read/write file in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, file, directory

I use fstream to read/write file in C++.
The structure of my project is:

```
project
    /folder
        source.cpp
        source.o
        source.out
        data.txt
        Makefile
```

My code to read file look like this:

> ifstream f;
>
> f.open("data.txt"); // because source.out is same directory with data.txt

But it can't read this file if I run it in Eclipse. It only work if I put `data.txt` file like this:

```
project
    /folder
        source.cpp
        source.o
        source.out
        Makefile    
    data.txt
```

It's not good. I also don't want to fix my code to:

> f.open("folder/data.txt")

when they are in same directory. Because if I run source.out outside eclipse, it doesn't work.

Anybody can give me some solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "working directory" in the run configuration (arguments tab)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But which variable that means "current directory" in eclipse?

Comment: I would just browse the workspace. This stuff can be different when using a different build system